# How to Create VueJs App With WebSocket Server on Same Port

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm a bit of a JS and Vue noob and I'm trying to figure out how to run my Vue app and a websocket server for that app on the same port 80 (to later be put behind a reverse proxy). I am able to get this working as a simple http server with express, but I can't figure out how to do it with my Vue use case.

My goal is to run a single main.js with `npm run serve` and bind the websocket server and routes I'm setting up with the vue router all in one application, on the same port.

Here is the example for the simple HTTP case:
server.js

```js
'use strict';

let fs = require('fs');
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let WSServer = require('ws').Server;
let server = require('http').createServer();
let PORT = 8080

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// regular HTTP request and response
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Get index');
  fs.createReadStream('./index.html').pipe(res);
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  let message = req.body.message;
  console.log('Regular POST message: ', message);
  return res.json({ answer: 42 });
});

module.exports = app;

// Create web socket server on top of a regular http server
let wss = new WSServer({ server: server });

// Also mount the app here
server.on('request', app);

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {    
    console.log(`received: ${message}`);
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ answer: 42 }));
  });
});


server.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(`http/ws server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

But my question is how can I modify the default main.js vue file to do this?

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

---

import router from './router';
import store from './store';

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app');
```

Comment: You use socket.io as a tag, but I so not see it in your code. https://socket.io/get-started/chat